# UI Automation:iPhone app - how to tap "OK" button when an alert appears

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios-ui-automation

1) UIATarget [name:(null)value:(null) NSRect: {{2.7520829e-39,2.0667855e-36},{0, 1.4012985e-45}}]

2) UIAApplication [name:tosh.0    value:(null) NSRect:{{0, 20}, {320,    460}}]

3) UIAWindow [name:(null) value:(null) NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}]

4)....

5)....

3) UIAWindow [name:(null) value:(null) NSRect:{{0, 0}, {320, 480}}]

4) UIAAlert [name:(null) value:(null) NSRect:{{18, 180}, {284, 141}}]

5) UIAStaticText [name:Unable to connect value:(null) NSRect: {{30, 225}, {260, 21}}]

5) UIAButton [name:OK value:(null) NSRect: {{29, 262},   {262, 43}}]

How can I press "OK" on the second UIAWindow, please. give syntax.

Answer (score 6):

If an allert appears, a callback in your automation script gets active. If you just want to dismiss it with the default behavour you should implement it like that:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) 
{   
    return false; 
}
```

The allert will be dismissed by returning false. If you want to click OK explizitely implement it like that:

```
alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
return true; // to bypass the default handler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an info, just use an UIAlertView/UIView without any buttons and hide it after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
But are you using Instruments and UIAutomation? it is not clear from your question for what technology you need code/syntax.

For Instruments+UIAutomation+JavaScript, it can be like this:

```
   UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().elements()[1].tap();
```

or

```
   UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().defaultButton().tap();
```

Comment: Thx, but I would also look into Rene answer, you could use (...).alert().buttons()["OK"].tap() or (...).alert().elements()["OK"].tap() to make code more readable. I personally avoid hardcoded calls like elements()[3], unless performance becomes an issue.